# How to mine multiwords by taking into account their position in the text?

Tags: r, string, text-mining

I want to extract certain words positioned between years and the following comma in a given text. Although the term `Mining` appears before & after `2020` in `text`, I need the later one which is found between `(2020)` and `,`. The same concept apply for the term `Computer Science` in the following `text`.

```
library(stringr)
text <- "This is text Mining exercise (2020) Mining, p. 628508; Computer Science text analysis (1998) Computer Science, p.345-355; Introduction to data mining (2015) J. Data Science, pp. 31-33"
comp <- c("Mining", "Computer Science", "J. Data Science")
pattern <- str_c(comp,collapse ="|")
data <- str_extract_all(text, pattern)
```

The last line of the above code gives an output of:

```
[1] "Mining" "Mining" "Computer Science" "Computer Science" "J. Data Science"
```

The output that I'm looking for is:

```
[1] "Mining" "Computer Science" "J. Data Science"
```

**Note**: The position of those words matter. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps wrap with `unique(data)`

Comment: Or if you want to use corresponding 'comp', then `str_extract(text, comp)`

Comment: The position of those words matter for me.

Comment: Does this work? I think this ignores `Mining`.

Comment: Please check my code in the solution posted below.  There was a typo in the commented one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need to extract between the `)` after the digit and the `,`, create a regex lookaround

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(text, str_c("(?<=\\(\\d{4}\\)\\s)(", pattern, ")(?=,)"))[[1]]
#[1] "Mining"           "Computer Science" "J. Data Science"
```

Comment: This works fine. Can I ask you the purpose of `[[1]]` in the code? I'm going to use this in the loop.

Comment: @Gadaa As it is a vector of  `list` with length 1, i extracted the `list` element as a vector with `[[1]]`

Comment: Great! I will come to you lif I come across some challenges on this issue. Appreciate!

Comment: Given that everything is ok, how to make the expression `\\d{4}` consider number start with either 20 or 19?

Comment: @Gadaa If that is the case you can do `\\d{19,20}`

Comment: Can I possibly get a link or material that helps me to understand `(?<=` and `(?=,)` in the above expression. Although I understood others, I'm still struggling to know the role of these expressions. Tnx!

Comment: @Gadaa you can check [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for more info.  Hope it helps